# Is there any way to change the underline color in Mac preview app?

Tags: macos, pdf, colors, macos-ventura

It is convenient to read PDFs using the preview app, but the annotation options are relatively few. The underline color seems can only be red, is there any way to change the color? I think there must be a way to achieve this, but Apple has hidden this very deeply. I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide a way to customize annotation tools.